# Datastructure ordered by insertion which can get length of subset

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, hashset, treeset

I am looking for a datastructure in Java sorted by insertion which can quickly find and remove a specific element and count the number of elements added after this element.

*LinkedHashSet* theoretically fulfills this requirement, but the interface does not give any methods to for example create an *Iterator* starting at a specified element. I would always have to iterate through the whole set.

Thanks for any suggestion.

**edit:**
OK, my simplistic implementation of (not really) LinkedHashSet for exactly my and only my use case currently is the following, just in case anyone is interested. This could be changed to include the possibility of actually iterating through the elements and not just to be able to count the amount of elements. Might need some refactoring, too...

```
public class DoublyLinkedHashSet<T> {
private final Map<T, Entry> map;
private Entry youngestEntry;

public DoublyLinkedHashSet() {
    this.map = new HashMap<T, Entry>();
}

public int size() {
    return map.size();
}

public boolean contains(final T element) {
    return map.containsKey(element);
}

public void add(final T element) {
    final Entry newEntry = new Entry();
    final Entry entryForElement = map.put(element, newEntry);
    boolean entryWasNotAlreadyInSet = entryForElement == null;
    if (entryWasNotAlreadyInSet) {
        newEntry.previousEntry = youngestEntry;
        if (youngestEntry != null) {
            youngestEntry.hasNext = true;
            youngestEntry.nextEntry = newEntry;
        }
    }
    youngestEntry = newEntry;
}

public void remove(final T element) {
    removeEntry(element);
}

public int removeAndGetAmountOfEntriesAfter(final T element) {
    Entry startEntry = removeEntry(element);

    if (startEntry == null) {
        return 0;
    }

    return countAllNextEntries(startEntry);
}

private int countAllNextEntries(final Entry startEntry) {
    int amount = 0;
    Entry currentEntry = startEntry;
    while (currentEntry.hasNext) {
        amount++;
        currentEntry = currentEntry.nextEntry;
    }
    return amount;
}

private Entry removeEntry(final T element) {
    final Entry removedEntry = map.remove(element);

    if (removedEntry == null) {
        return null;
    }

    if (hasPreviousAndNextEntry(removedEntry)) {
        final Entry previousEntry = removedEntry.previousEntry;
        final Entry nextEntry = removedEntry.previousEntry;
        connect(previousEntry, nextEntry);
    } else if (isEndOfList(removedEntry)) {
        final Entry previousEntry = removedEntry.previousEntry;
        resetEndTo(previousEntry);
    } else if (isHead(removedEntry)) {
        final Entry nextEntry = removedEntry.nextEntry;
        resetHeadTo(nextEntry);
    }

    return removedEntry;
}

private boolean hasPreviousAndNextEntry(final Entry entry) {
    return entry.hasPrevious && entry.hasNext;
}

private void connect(final Entry previousEntry, final Entry nextEntry) {
    previousEntry.nextEntry = nextEntry;
}

private boolean isHead(final Entry entry) {
    return !entry.hasPrevious && entry.hasNext;
}

private void resetHeadTo(final Entry entry) {
    entry.previousEntry = null;
    entry.hasPrevious = false;
}

private boolean isEndOfList(final Entry removedEntry) {
    return removedEntry.hasPrevious && !removedEntry.hasNext;
}

private void resetEndTo(final Entry entry) {
    entry.nextEntry = null;
    entry.hasNext = false;
    youngestEntry = entry;
}

private static final class Entry {
    private boolean hasNext;
    private boolean hasPrevious;
    private Entry nextEntry;
    private Entry previousEntry;
}
}
```

Comment: LinkedHashSet has everything you need, but i'm afraid it's hidden from it's clients.

Comment: Don't make me cry ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use a [SortedSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html). It provides a [tailSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html#tailSet%28E%29) method that should do what you need.

You can sort them on insertion order by adding a sequence number to your objects and sorting on that.

Comment: I was convinced for a while this was a good idea and then didn't think about it for a while. However: This way I can only remove an element in log(n) time if I have saved the sequence number with the object, since that is what it is sorted by. My first idea was to add a HashMap to to find the sequence number with the hash of my object. That seems silly though. I guess I will just implement my own SinglyLinkedHashSet since I can delegate most methods to HashSet. Will post the code for posterity.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), or is there some reason why you can't use it?

```
public int removeAndCount(Object o){
    int i = list.indexOf(o);
    list.remove(o);
    return list.size() - i;
}
```

Comment: That's not efficient enough, it's linear on find, and it could be logarithmic with hashed collections.

Comment: Yes but Lists keep track of indexes, unlike Sets. and I think that's exactly what he needs.

Comment: The problem with this is that not only is indexOf(Object) linear, so is add. getting the remaining length of the list is constant time obviously, but that won't outweigh the many add calls in my case.

Comment: Add(obj)  is constant time, only add(obj, x) is not.

Comment: Ups, you're right. Still indexOf and remove are linear in contrast to both being log(n) if I would actually be able to use a LinkedHashSet.

Comment: Are your objects added at the end of or in the middle of your Collection?

Comment: Added at end, so you were right. But removed and asked for containment in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

Have a hashed collection which holds your objects, and maintain a list next to them (this is what LinkedHashMap does for example, which would be so nice for you but it hides it's inner list). If your hashed collection's elements have the index of the same element in the list, you can just jump to your list at the given index and iterate throught the rest of it with ease. I think all of the operations you mentioned need sub-linear time to run with this solution, except which can't be faster (iteration on ~n elements will always take ~n time)

Example solution with HashMap and LinkedList:

find: `HashMap.get(key)` holds the index in your list, `key` is your element. log(n) time

remove: `LinkedList.remove(HashMap.get(key))`,  HashMap.remove(key), and your element is gone. log(n) time

iterate:

```
for (i=HashMap.get(key); i<LinkedList.size(); i++){
     //etc
}
```

You probably need to unwrap the LinkedList too, since .get(index) I bet takes linear time to run.

Comment: Are you sure LinkedList.remove is logn. In order to find the nth element I need to iterate through the list each time, which should be linear.

Comment: "You probably need to unwrap the LinkedList too, since .get(index) I bet takes linear time to run." <- Unwrap LinkedList too, it has what you need, just hides it..